# What is the best way to remove double quotes from strings set using MySQL _FETCH?

Tags: mysql, ajax, json, double, quotes

I have a php script to retrieve data from a MysQL databse following an ajax call.  The data needs to be returned to the calling web page as a string representing a series of x,y values to be displayed on a scatter graph.

The required format which the php script needs to output to the calling page (which will pick it up from xmlhttp.responseText) is as follows:

> [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5],[6,6],[7,7]]

What I am getting is:

> [[0,"69.08"],[1,"53.53"],[2,"61.61"],[3,"72.04"],[4,"82.72"],[5,"103.76"]]

The PHP code I am using to build the return string is:

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res_Data,MYSQL_NUM)) { 

  $index[$i] = $i;
  $PointArray[0] = $i;
  $PointArray[1] = $row[1];
  $ReturnData[$i] = $PointArray;
  $i = $i + 1;
}

echo json_encode($ReturnData);
```

Interestingly, when I echo the data to a html table displayed on the calling page rather than setting it as a php array, no double quotes appear.

My questions is twofold:

(1) Is there a more elegant way of building the data string than what I have come up with which appears a bit clumsy?

(2) What's the best way to remove the double quotes - should this be done server side or in the javascript function on the web page initiating the call?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want quotes to appear - just don't put a strings in array ;-)

Replace your code to something like (I added `(float)` modifier before `$row[1]`):

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res_Data,MYSQL_NUM)) { 

  $index[$i] = $i;
  $PointArray[0] = $i;
  $PointArray[1] = (float)$row[1];
  $ReturnData[$i] = $PointArray;
  $i = $i + 1;
}
```

Or a little more compact:

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res_Data,MYSQL_NUM)) { 
  $index[$i] = $i; // what is it used for?
  $ReturnData[$i] = array($i, (float)$row[1]);
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: @nortyrich: if my answer helped you - check it ;-)